# next.js pages route with folder makes 'not found 404' error

Tags: next.js

The route **/competitions/[id]/build** is not working.

Here is my folder.

```
/ 

ㄴ pages 

  ㄴ competitions 

    ㄴ [id] 

       ㄴ detail.js 

       ㄴ build 

          ㄴ index.js 

          ㄴ about.js 

          ㄴ crew.js
```

**/competitions/0/detail** => working 
**/competitions/0/build** => not working 
**/competitions/0/build/about** => not working 
**/competitions/0/build/crew** => not working

How can I route to pages in **'build'** folder?

Comment: Did you try a different folder name? Might the `build` be a reserved keyword or something?

Comment: Can you share the error it's showing, or properly check react component that is default exported or not on not working files.

Comment: _"The route /competitions/[id]/build is not working"_ - can you be more specific? Do you get any error? Can you share the code for the pages that don't work?

Comment: There are 'not found 404' error. And there are 'teams' folder in same folder with 'build' folder. teams are 404 error too

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer.

Make other routes with file to folder.
For example,

```
/ 

ㄴ pages 

  ㄴ competitions 

    ㄴ [id] 

       ㄴ detail.js 

       ㄴ build 

          ㄴ index.js 

          ㄴ about.js 

          ㄴ crew.js
```

If your directory look like this, change to

```
/ 

ㄴ pages 

  ㄴ competitions 

    ㄴ [id] 

      ㄴ detail
          ㄴ index.js

       ㄴ build 

          ㄴ index.js 

          ㄴ about.js 

          ㄴ crew.js
```

**detail.js** changed to **detail/index.js**